# ansible playbook for virt commnd status check

Tags: ansible

I am using below playbook to wait until vm status is running and perform next tasks once vm is running.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

          - name: wait for the vm to shut down
            virt:
               command: status
               name: myCentosVM
            register: vmstatus
            until: vmstatus.status == 'running'
            retries: 1500
            delay: 10
```

But I am seeing error like

```
the conditional check 'vmstatus.status == 'running'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (vmstatus.status == 'running'): 'dict object' has no attribute 'status'"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
the conditional check 'vmstatus.status == 'running'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (vmstatus.status == 'running'): 'dict object' has no attribute 'status'
```

Your error is self explanatory. Variable Vmstatus doesn't contain any attribute like status. So, you can't use vmstatus.status.
First run

```
- name: wait for the vm to shut down
  virt:
    command: status
    name: myCentosVM
  register: vmstatus
- debug: var=vmstatus
```

It will print a list of attributes output contains and accordingly u can apply check condition.

If issue persists, Kindly share debug output here.

Comment: If Iuse debug statement, it throws error like `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The `libvirt` module is not importable. Check the requirements."}`

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The `libvirt` module is not importable. Check the requirements."} this error will easily be removed by installing libvirt-python package. for Centos7 install libvirt-python-4.5.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm and for centos8 install el8 pkg. After that you will easily get your debug output.
TASK [debug] 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all_vms": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "list_vms": []
    }
}

Comment: I was not able to figure it out how to install in ubuntu 20.04, if you have idea how it can be done in ubuntu20.04, please let me know. Don't mine can you share the output `debug: var=vmstatus`.

Comment: actually I dont have any VM on my server So I cant run status command pointing some VM's name.Use  pip install libvirt-python on ubuntu server it will surely help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your dictionary key `status` won't be defined along the retries, up until the command succeeds (or gives a non-zero return code).

To deal with those cases, you can use the built-in test [`defined`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#defined) of Jinja.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - virt:
        command: status
        name: myCentosVM
      register: vm
      until: vm.status is defined and vm.status == 'running'
      retries: 1500
      delay: 10
```